# Is there a way to determine AWS SES service availability in a region?

Tags: .net-core-2.1, aws-sdk-net

Is there a way to determine if ses has a local region available using AWS SDK?
After registering e-mail service with Core Middleware `services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSimpleEmailService>()` I want to find and assign the SES local region to e-mail service if there is one available. Using .Net Core 2.1 and AWS SDK. Thank you!

Comment: the supported regions are documents in AWS docs. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/regions.html

Comment: @ArunK I am trying to determine if there a region local to my SES service, and assign that region to SES service. of there is 1

Comment: sorry I don't follow. let's say your dot.net core application runs in `ap-southeast-2`, then you want to initialize your code to `const ses = new AWS.SES({region: 'ap-southeast-2'})`. is that what you are trying to do.

Comment: Right now we have to pass region from Configuration like so ```services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSimpleEmailService>(Configuration.GetAWSOptions(AwsSes))```. I need to add logic that if app runs in ```ap-southeast-2``` it use that for SES service instead of relying on config settings

Comment: Not sure there is a better way. I would store all the SES supported regions in config (maybe an array) then check whether the region of the service is one of the SES supported regions stored in the config, I will use the region if it is.

Comment: @ArunK This is better then using config but still less then ideal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211329/discussion-between-arun-k-and-victor).

Comment: By default the ses account is in sandbox mode. Are you thinking applying live ses accounts on all the region's ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this link contains information you are interested in - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-query-for-aws-regions-endpoints-and-more-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/

> Here’s how to get the list of regions where a service (Amazon Athena,
>   in this case) is available:

```
$ aws ssm get-parameters-by-path \
  --path /aws/service/global-infrastructure/services/athena/regions --output json | \
  jq .Parameters[].Value
"ap-northeast-2"
"ap-south-1"
"ap-southeast-2"
"ca-central-1"
"eu-central-1"
"eu-west-1"
"eu-west-2"
"us-east-1"
"us-east-2"
"us-gov-west-1"
"ap-northeast-1"
"ap-southeast-1"
"us-west-2"
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.SimpleSystemsManagement/ NuGet package can be used to achieve same via .NET SDK. For your example the code to get the set of regions where SES is available can look like

```cs
var client = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(...);
var path = "/aws/service/global-infrastructure/services/ses/regions";
var response = await client.GetParametersByPathAsync(new GetParametersByPathRequest
{
    Path = path
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
var regions = new HashSet<string>(response.Parameters.Select(x => x.Value));

while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.NextToken))
{
    response = await client.GetParametersByPathAsync(new GetParametersByPathRequest
    {
        Path = path,
        NextToken = response.NextToken
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    foreach (var parameter in response.Parameters) regions.Add(parameter.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. There is probably no way to get that using .NET SDK

Comment: @Victor you can use the .NET AWS SDK, I added the code sample in the answer.